# IIS Rewrite IP:Port to {domain}/{thing}

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

What I'm trying to do:

- I own a domain, let's say **blahblahblah.com**
- On the server, it points to **:80** and **:443** properly - this is working
- I want to remap so that if a user visits **blahblahblah.com/*thing1*** then it maps to **localhost:5000**
- Similarly, I also want to remap so that if a user visits **blahblahblah.com/*thing2*** then it maps to another server and port on my local network (not exposed to the internet)

I essentially want to use my webserver to communicate with other servers on my network and other ports through "sub directories" or whatever they are called in this instance (site/subdir, site2/subdir). I've been trying to solve this issue for days! I've installed ARR (and enabled the Proxy) and the URL Rewrite modules on my IIS.

I've attempted god knows how many different rewrite templates on SO. I can get partial success, in which the route /thingx/ resolves, but all the resources are referencing blahblahblah.com and (appropriately) can't find the resources for the site at that address.

Current rewrite (resolves *some* resources at **blahblahblah.com/*thing1***, but others are misrouted):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Thing1" enabled="true">
       <match url="(thing1*)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**EDIT:** I've updated my rules to the below, as per this article from Microsoft Docs: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) . These rewrites supposedly do exactly what I need, but the result is not the same in my case, and I still have no clue why.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Thing1" enabled="true">
        <match url="^thing1/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:5000/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add application prefix" preCondition="IsHTML">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(thing1)/.*" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/{C:1}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsHTML">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

**More Notes:**

- `localhost:5000` works as expected
- `localhost/thing1` resolves in 404 Not Found
- `blahblahblah.com/thing1` resolves in pulling in the default HTML page, but none of the assets (javascript, css, etc), they return 404 Not Found.

**EDIT:** It may be important to note that these rules have been written into the default site (bound to :80, :443) on IIS' `web.config`. Writing these rules in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` results in a 500.

Any feedback on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need ARR so as to route requests to another machine, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module and also the rules should look slightly different. Microsoft has separate articles on ARR.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I've been through those docs already, and ARR has been enabled as I stated above.

I've gone through this example again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

 
The current scenario is this (which isn't the same result as the docs promise):

- localhost/thing1 returns a 404 not found

- blahblahblah.com/thing1 returns SOME resources, but fails to get anything past localhost:5000/*

- localhost:5000 works fine as expected

Comment: @Thomas Ummm.. so what did you do? :D

Comment: @Kinani thank you for keeping me honest. Posted the answer we ended up using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of this was due to the way SPAs are handled (# and history mode), but I ended up solving with the below webconfig for IIS, which allows me to nest everything under a `/foobar` endpoint:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules> 
        <rule name="Subdirectory Index" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^foobar/index\.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Subdirectory Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/foobar/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```